# SQL Server: Left Join and unmatch rows are not coming

Tags: t-sql

I am using left join as a result everything should come from my left table but only matching data coming. I am not able to understand what is wrong in my query or what is missing in it. so please have a look at sample code where anyone can run and reproduce the issue.

```
create table #tmpModel
(
    CSM_ID int, 
    ID INT,
    ParentID INT,
    DisplayInCSM Varchar(200), 
    Type varchar(20), 
    LineItemID INT
)

create table #tmpLineItem
(
    ID INT,
    LineItem Varchar(200), 
    TickerID varchar(20), 
)

create table #tmpOutputDetl_CSMTuner
(
    Section     Varchar(200), 
    LineItem    Varchar(200), 
    Period      Varchar(200),
    ItemValue   Decimal(18,2),
    Ticker      varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO #tmpModel(CSM_ID,ID,ParentID,DisplayInCSM,Type,LineItemID)
VALUES (370,1,0,'Model','SHEET',0)
       ,(370,2,1,'Segment Details','GROUP',0)
       ,(370,3,2,'LoyaltyOne','GROUP',0)
       ,(370,4,3,'Revenue','LINEITEM',198359)
       ,(370,5,4,'EBITDA','LINEITEM',198360)
       ,(370,6,5,'Card Services','GROUP',0)
       ,(370,7,6,'Diluted','LINEITEM',198342)

INSERT INTO #tmpLineItem(ID,LineItem,TickerID)
VALUES (198359,'Net Revenue','ADK')
       ,(198360,'EBITDA Details','ADK')
       ,(198342,'Diluted Shares','ADK')

INSERT INTO #tmpOutputDetl_CSMTuner (Section,LineItem,Period,ItemValue,Ticker)
VALUES ('Consensus Model','Net Revenue','2010 FYA',203.22,'ADS')
    ,('Consensus Model','Net Revenue','2011 FYA',203.22,'ADS')
    ,('Consensus Model','Net Revenue','2012 FYA',203.22,'ADS')
    ,('Consensus Model','EBITDA Details','2010 FYA',103.22,'ADS')
    ,('Consensus Model','EBITDA Details','2011 FYA',109.22,'ADS')
    ,('Consensus Model','EBITDA Details','2012 FYA',105.22,'ADS')
    ,('Key Financial','Diluted Shares','2010 FYA',55.22,'ADS')
    ,('Key Financial','Diluted Shares','2011 FYA',20.22,'ADS')
    ,('Key Financial','Diluted Shares','2012 FYA',13.22,'ADS')

;with DirectReports as 
(
    select      CSM_ID, 
                ID, 
                ParentID, 
                hierarchy = format(id,'0000'), 
                level = 0,
                DisplayInCSM, 
                Type,
                LineItemID

    from        #tmpModel 
    where       isnull(ParentID, 0) = 0

    union all
    select      e.CSM_ID,
                e.ID, 
                e.ParentID, 
                hierarchy = d.hierarchy + '.' + format(e.id,'0000'), 
                level = level + 1,
                e.DisplayInCSM, 
                e.Type,
                e.LineItemID

    from        #tmpModel e
    join        DirectReports d on e.ParentID = d.ID
)

/*SELECT * FROM DirectReports Order By hierarchy*/


,Cte1 as 
(
    SELECT AA.Section,AA.LineItem,AA.Ticker, r.DisplayInCSM, r.Type,r.hierarchy, AA.ItemValue, AA.Period
    FROM DirectReports r 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (                                                  
        Select b.*,L.ID AS LineItemID,L.TickerID                                                     
        From #tmpOutputDetl_CSMTuner b                                                  
        INNER JOIN #tmpLineItem L ON b.LineItem= L.LineItem         
        WHERE L.TickerID='ADK' AND b.Ticker='ADS'
    ) AA
    ON (AA.LineItemID=r.LineItemID)
    WHERE AA.Ticker = 'ADS'

)

SELECT * FROM Cte1 ORDER By hierarchy

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tmpModel') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #tmpModel
END

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tmpLineItem') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #tmpLineItem
END

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tmpOutputDetl_CSMTuner') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #tmpOutputDetl_CSMTuner
END
```

1. Data should come with Parent child hierarchy wise
2. Type **Group** should come but not coming, only **Line Item** is coming.

Please guide me which area i should rectify to get the desired output.

Comment: `WHERE AA.Ticker = 'ADS'` can never be true if no row is returned; what you have is an implicit `INNER JOIN`, not a `LEFT JOIN`. Move the clause to the subquery or into the `ON` of the outer query.

Comment: One humble request can you please write few line which i can use at my end to get desired output. thanks

Comment: @Larnu Thanks i change the code bit as per your guide line and it worked as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this way comment this line **/*WHERE AA.Ticker = 'ADS'*/**

Now right data is coming.

```
 create table #tmpModel
 (
     CSM_ID int, 
     ID INT,
     ParentID INT,
     DisplayInCSM Varchar(200), 
     Type varchar(20), 
     LineItemID INT
 )
    
 create table #tmpLineItem
 (
     ID INT,
     LineItem Varchar(200), 
     TickerID varchar(20), 
 )
    
 create table #tmpOutputDetl_CSMTuner
 (
     Section        Varchar(200), 
     LineItem    Varchar(200), 
     Period        Varchar(200),
     ItemValue    Decimal(18,2),
     Ticker        varchar(20)
 )
    
 INSERT INTO #tmpModel(CSM_ID,ID,ParentID,DisplayInCSM,Type,LineItemID)
 VALUES (370,1,0,'Model','SHEET',0)
        ,(370,2,1,'Segment Details','GROUP',0)
        ,(370,3,2,'LoyaltyOne','GROUP',0)
        ,(370,4,3,'Revenue','LINEITEM',198359)
        ,(370,5,4,'EBITDA','LINEITEM',198360)
        ,(370,6,5,'Card Services','GROUP',0)
        ,(370,7,6,'Diluted','LINEITEM',198342)
    
 INSERT INTO #tmpLineItem(ID,LineItem,TickerID)
 VALUES (198359,'Net Revenue','ADK')
        ,(198360,'EBITDA Details','ADK')
        ,(198342,'Diluted Shares','ADK')
    
 INSERT INTO #tmpOutputDetl_CSMTuner (Section,LineItem,Period,ItemValue,Ticker)
 VALUES ('Consensus Model','Net Revenue','2010 FYA',203.22,'ADS')
     ,('Consensus Model','Net Revenue','2011 FYA',203.22,'ADS')
     ,('Consensus Model','Net Revenue','2012 FYA',203.22,'ADS')
     ,('Consensus Model','EBITDA Details','2010 FYA',103.22,'ADS')
     ,('Consensus Model','EBITDA Details','2011 FYA',109.22,'ADS')
     ,('Consensus Model','EBITDA Details','2012 FYA',105.22,'ADS')
     ,('Key Financial','Diluted Shares','2010 FYA',55.22,'ADS')
     ,('Key Financial','Diluted Shares','2011 FYA',20.22,'ADS')
     ,('Key Financial','Diluted Shares','2012 FYA',13.22,'ADS')
    
 ;with DirectReports as 
 (
     select      CSM_ID, 
                 ID, 
                 ParentID, 
                 hierarchy = format(id,'0000'), 
                 level = 0,
                 DisplayInCSM, 
                 Type,
                 LineItemID
    
     from        #tmpModel 
     where       isnull(ParentID, 0) = 0
    
     union all
     select      e.CSM_ID,
                 e.ID, 
                 e.ParentID, 
                 hierarchy = d.hierarchy + '.' + format(e.id,'0000'), 
                 level = level + 1,
                 e.DisplayInCSM, 
                 e.Type,
                 e.LineItemID
    
     from        #tmpModel e
     join        DirectReports d on e.ParentID = d.ID
 )
    
 /*SELECT * FROM DirectReports Order By hierarchy*/
    
    
 ,Cte1 as 
 (
     SELECT AA.Section,AA.LineItem,AA.Ticker, r.DisplayInCSM, r.Type,r.hierarchy, AA.ItemValue, AA.Period
     FROM DirectReports r 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (                                                  
         Select b.*,L.ID AS LineItemID,L.TickerID                                                     
         From #tmpOutputDetl_CSMTuner b                                                  
         INNER JOIN #tmpLineItem L ON b.LineItem= L.LineItem         
         WHERE L.TickerID='ADK' AND b.Ticker='ADS'
     ) AA
     ON (AA.LineItemID=r.LineItemID)
     /*WHERE AA.Ticker = 'ADS'*/
    
 )
    
 SELECT * FROM Cte1 WHERE TYPE <> 'SHEET' ORDER By hierarchy
    
 IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tmpModel') IS NOT NULL
 BEGIN
     DROP TABLE #tmpModel
 END
    
 IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tmpLineItem') IS NOT NULL
 BEGIN
     DROP TABLE #tmpLineItem
 END
    
 IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tmpOutputDetl_CSMTuner') IS NOT NULL
 BEGIN
     DROP TABLE #tmpOutputDetl_CSMTuner
 END
```